# Force android 7.0 into roaming for better connection

Tags: 7.0-nougat, mobile-network, roaming

I do a daily commute to work from country A to B. My mobile is from a phone company in country B, and travelling into B, the switch between country providers is handled rather gracefully. The problem comes when I travel back. It seems to me that since the phone knows it will start to roam, it tries to stay on country Bs network as long as possible, resulting in inferior network, or no network for quite some time.

Today I manually forced a switch of network (to a country As network), and voila, I am having good connection again at a place where I would usually be without mobile network.

I have a contract that covers roaming, so I am not worried about costs. I would like to make this thing more convenient - it currently involves manual intervention, waiting until all available networks are scanned, chosing one... How could this be done on a Samsung Galaxy S7, Android 7.0, which is currently not rooted?

Comment: The device is not rooted (question updated). If rooting would solve the problem, I might consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Try toggling airplane mode, which turns the mobile modem on/off and forces a reconnect. If that helps, maybe one of the "connection improver" apps around could help, which do this automatically.